# Can I drive a relay with a PCF8575?

Tags: relay, open-collector

I would like to drive a [relay](https://www.circuitbasics.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/SRD-05VDC-SL-C-Datasheet.pdf) using a [PCF8575](https://www.ti.com/product/PCF8575), which has "quasi-bidirectional input/output (I/O)" ports. If I understood properly, they are open-drain ports. Is this diagram OK? Do I need the transistor Q8, or can I get rid of it and connect directly the relay coil to the port and 5V?

[image: Circuit diagram]

Comment: @user263983 They're quasi-bidirectional- there's a strong P-channel in parallel (activated during transient conditions) with a weak P-channel pullup so no resistor is required.

Answer (score 0):

The guaranteed drive strength of the PCF8575 is 30 µA when sourcing current (I<sub>OH</sub>) and 10 mA when sinking current (I<sub>OL</sub>). The relay needs 70 mA, which is not only way too much, but also exceeds the absolute maximum ratings of the PCF and might damage it.

It would be possible to use eight output pins of the PCF in parallel.

If you use the transistor, take care to give it enough base current; R17 should be at most 1 kΩ.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot expect the PCF8575 to directly drive the relay correctly. Look at the relay datasheet for the coil resistance- 70Ω+/-10% @ 20°C. That results in far too much current for the PCF8575 (again, look at the datasheet).

You've specified the lowest beta bin of BC857 (A), which is a fairly wimpy transistor to start with. I'm not sure how you came up with the value of R17- it should be much lower, you'd want more like 1K, but even with Ic/Ib = 20, the transistor [datasheet](https://www.mouser.ca/datasheet/2/916/BC856_BC857_BC858-1318701.pdf) allows 650mV drop at 100mA. That eats up about half of the allowance for temperature increase above 20°C. It's probably okay for a hobby application if that's all you have laying around, but for a commercial design a better transistor for 70mA operation wouldn't be amiss and there would be negligible cost delta. For example, an MMBT4403 PNP transistor with a 500Ω to 1000Ω base resistor. Or even an AO3401 P-channel MOSFET (in which case the 10k gate resistor would be okay).

Compare the Vce(sat) curve of BC857A at currents over a few tens of mA

[image]

with MMBT4403 at your ~70mA nominal.

[image]

Comment: Great explanation! Regarding the resistor, my mistake. It was initally 1K for that transistor. I will evaluate replacing the BC857A for a more suitable one. Thanks!